# How to make voice reading work in different voices?

Tags: adobe-reader, text-to-speech-voices

I got a problem with Acrobat Reader... it has function to read text (by voice), but it seems to work only on English with default voice option checked.

I can uncheck option "use default voice" and select voice from a list:

1. Microsoft Paulina Desktop - Polish
2. Microsoft Zira Desktop - English
   (United States)

Neither of them work; nothing is being read.

Anybody know how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try another software. It is possible a problem with Adobe Acrobat.

Also - if nothing is being read when you check the other voice, it could be an installation problem for the voice.

You should add which operating system you are using.